# Mysql and flask in docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask

Hi I am using flask and MySQL it works on my local machine perfectly but I want to put it in docker container I get the following error:
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Can someone please help me, where I am doing wrong?
my dockderfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

EXPOSE 5000 

WORKDIR /virtual-staging
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip vim iputils-ping python3-mysqldb
# COPY requirements.txt app.py config.py /virtual-staging/
COPY . /virtual-staging

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

and my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    links:
      - "db"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV= production
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

any my **config.py** file:

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    MYSQl_USER = 'root'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'root'
    MYSQL_HOST = "mysql"
    MYSQL_PORT = "3306"
    MYSQL_DB = "virtualstaging"
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `MYSQL_HOST` in your configuration to `db`.

Docker-compose creates host definitions for services defined in a compose file available through docker network created by docker-compose for the application stack.

Also the `links` is really not necessary. I would advise to use `depends_on` instead in order to create the `db` service before the `app` one.